# Calculate limit of ln function with trigonometric functions

Tags: limits

I need help with solving this function, because I have tried and everything leads nowhere. I can use only basic function limits e.g $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$. I cannot use L'Hopital, deratives and so on: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x)+\sin(x^2)\right)}{x^4}$$ as x approaches 0
The answer should be 1/3.

Comment: hint: use $cos^2x = 1-sin^2x$

Answer (score 3):

Using the well-known limit
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=1$$
you obtain
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\cos^2x+\sin\left(x^2\right)\right)}{x^4}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x+\sin\left(x^2\right)-1}{x^4}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sin^2x+\sin\left(x^2\right)-1}{x^4}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(x^2\right)-\sin^2x}{x^4}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2\right)}+\sin x\right)\left(\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2\right)}-\sin x\right)}{x^4}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2\right)}+\sin x}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2\right)}-\sin x}{x^3}\\&=2\cdot\frac16\\&=\frac13\end{align}$$

Here is how the last two limits are calculated

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2\right)}+\sin x}{x}&=\sqrt{(\pm1)^2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}}+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\\&=\sqrt{1}+1\\&=1+1\\&=2\end{align}$$

The second limit is computed similarly. The $\text{sgn}(x)$ is [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). When we square and apply square root, we want to preserve the sign of this term, so adding $\text{sgn}(x)$ will fix the problem.

Comment: How did get the last answer?

Comment: @haqnatural. Are you talking about the left or the right limit in the 3rd row from the end?

Comment: I am talking about both limit, you just put 2 and 1/6 without explanation

Comment: @haqnatural. I Thought it is obvious, sorry. Answer updated.

Comment: I figured out the first one, but could you please explain the second?

Comment: @ThePirateBay the last limit which you said it was 1/6 according to wolfram doesn't have a limit because the left and right limit are different

Comment: @YoannaE. Yes, I forgot to add the signum function. Thanks for spotting it. The answer has been updated, please check it again.